# How to overwrite .inner-scroll class background color?

Tags: ionic4

I am using Ionic V4,  tag. 
In that .inner-scroll class there.
I am unable to override .inner-scroll class in my home.page.scss

Comment: what do you mean by unable to override ? could you share some code and tell us what is exactly that isn't working ?

Comment: Below code is from ionic style:    
.inner-scroll {
    padding-left: unset;
    padding-right: unset;
    -webkit-padding-start: var(--padding-start);
    padding-inline-start: var(--padding-start);
    -webkit-padding-end: var(--padding-end);
    padding-inline-end: var(--padding-end);
}
I have override like below

.inner-scroll {
    background: #d33939 !important;
}
But, My background color not at all apply.

Answer (score 3):

You can style elements inside of an ionic shadow tree using ::part pseudo-element in this way:

```
ion-content::part(scroll) {
    position: relative;
}
```

This code should add *position: relative* to *ion-content main.inner-scroll* element if it has part="scroll" attribute

Feel free to check more info here:
https://www.joshmorony.com/using-shadow-parts-to-style-protected-shadow-dom-components/
https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: white;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #d33939 ;
}
```